# Can I use objects instead of conditionals for Clean Code Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, conditional-statements

I have a conditional on `:environment` to set eCommerce symbols for transactions.  When I'm developing, I want the test account to be used.

```
if :environemnt == 'development'
    :ssl_merchant_id  = '001234'
    :ssl_user_id      = 'windoe6'
    :ssl_pin          = 'ABCDE'
elsif :environemnt == 'production'
    :ssl_merchant_id  = '006543'
    :ssl_user_id      = 'dingbat32'
    :ssl_pin          = 'AKEIN'
end
```

I want to use class definitions and object creation to avoid conditionals.  Clean Code suggests doing so. I can't see getting around a conditional to choose either of these sets of symbols.

Is it possible to use class definitions to avoid conditionals?  I would still have to create two classes, then choose a class, which has to be chosen in the code.  There's still a trigger which chooses what object to use or create.  Can it be done, and how can it be done?

Comment: Your conditional will never be true `:environemnt == :development` will always be false and the second one is not actually a condition at all. Additionally `Symbols` are not variables and cannot be assigned as above

Comment: And `:ssl_pin = 'AKEIN'` is a syntax error

Comment: @engineersmnky ok I will modify the conditional.  Why is the second option not a condition?

Comment: Because when I posted that it said else and not elsif but either way now both both conditions will always be false since a symbol will never equal a string

Comment: OK, I see.  I'll go with @mrzasa's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use hashes with config if you really want to avoid conditionals:

```
config = {
  development: {
    ssl_merchant_id: '001234'
    ssl_user_id: 'windoe6'
    ssl_pin: 'ABCDE'
  }
  production: { 
    ssl_merchant_id: '006543'
    ssl_user_id: 'dingbat32'
    ssl_pin: 'AKEIN'
  }
}

config[environment.to_sym]
```

Comment: +1 Sometimes a hash is all you need. If you later need an object, that object can replace the hash and provide a `[]` method for compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Using objects you'd create a Factory like this:

```
class Environment
  attr_accessor :ssl_merchant_id, :ssl_user_id, :ssl_pin
end

class Development < Environment
  def initialize
    @ssl_merchant_id  = '001234'
    @ssl_user_id      = 'windoe6'
    @ssl_pin          = 'ABCDE'
  end
end

class Production < Environment
  def initialize
    @ssl_merchant_id  = '006543'
    @ssl_user_id      = 'dingbat32'
    @ssl_pin          = 'AKEIN'
  end
end

class EnvironmentFactory
  def self.build(environment)
    Kernel.const_get(environment.to_s.capitalize).new
  end
end

EnvironmentFactory.build(<:development or :production>)
```

This is a "more object oriented" version of [mrzasa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53528768/33226). Typically you'll want to stick with the config based version until your objects need this level of complexity and overhead.

This type of pattern is more used in Java / .NET than Ruby and you won't find it commonly used in practice.

Comment: I'd suggest a hybrid of @mrzasa's answer. Put the initialization info into a constant. Initialize from the constant. This avoids hard coding configuration in the class and prevents an unnecessary amount of subclasses. And remember, Hashes are objects.

Comment: @Schwern in a real environment I totally agree with you. I would die inside if I saw a setup class like this :P

Comment: Doesn't code get super bloated this way?  It seems like a lot to make a simple choice of values.

Comment: @Rich_F when you get to the level of complexity where something like this is warranted you're going to need abstractions. It's impossible to work in a system without good abstractions. It *can* bloat code, but so can tons of switch and if/else statements. Ask yourself what happens when you want to attach behaviour to configuration. Where do those methods go? Passing around arrays and hashes is easy to write, but can be hard to debug down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Objects; no conditionals:

```
# a Struct is just a fast way of creating a class
SSldata = Struct.new(:ssl_merchant_id, :ssl_user_id, :ssl_pin) 

development = SSldata.new('001234', 'windoe6', 'ABCDE')
production  = SSldata.new('006543', 'dingbat32','AKEIN')

# demo    
environment = development

environment.ssl_pin # => "ABCDE"
```